# Is there a way I can purchase things using my itunes account?

Tags: itunes, itunes-store

Is it possible to purchase things on other sites using my iTunes account like paypal; to pay for items on sites other than the iTunes store?

How would this be done technically? I have came up with a few possible solutions but doubt them.
Would apple even allow this?

Thanks for any response.

Comment: do you mean use your iTunes account like paypal; to pay for items on sites other than the iTunes store? http://askubuntu.com/questions/70770/is-there-a-way-i-can-purchase-things-using-my-itunes-account

Comment: Yes exactly, I'll rephrase my question.

Answer (score 2):

You can't purchase things with your iTunes account except on the iTunes Store. Even if you happen to technically do it (Which is highly unlikely), iTunes Terms of service may not allow it.